# Add control to Asp page and position in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have a varying number of links that I need to add to a webpage using C#.  A little background may help so, the ultimate goal of this is to have the user select an area of a map and choose the data they would like to get from this map.  After the data reports have been generated, a link pops up for each area selected that is a download link for the report.

I can add new links fine, but I'd like to keep things centered on the page like the main control, but when I add a new hyperlink it keeps adding it to the left side.  I have my page style set to centered and I don't see the option in a hyperlink object to set it's position.  Is there any other way I can do this?

Forgive me but it's my first C# web app.

Thanks!

Comment: re:edit I don't think that saying Hi or thank you deterred in any way from the question so I reverted.  Thanks for your interest though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make yourself a

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="plhFoo" />
```

In the location that you want to add your dynamic stuff to, and then add your controls to this, instead of the page.

-- Edit

If you want to position it, you may put a

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlFoo" CssClass="someclass" />
```

And style `someclass`; because the panel will render as a div.